# MySQL - SAME query with one variabile change take more then 10x longer

Tags: mysql, caching, optimization

I have MySQL DB where I always ask same "question", only thing I change is VIN variabile in query.

To be more specific I show you 2 querys:
Firsth one with VIN: `U5YFF24128L064909` (takes 0.0002 sec)

```
SELECT  c.vin, c.case_id, c.claimnumber, c.platenumber, c.axrmrs_id,
        c.insurer_memberid, c.country, c.date_created, c.totalloss,
        c.lastcalc_manufacturer_code, c.lastcalc_model_code, c.lastcalc_submodel_code,
        c.audavin_triggered, c.accident_date, c.registration_date,
        c.manufacturing_year, cl.spareparts, cl.totalcosts, cl.laborhours,
        cl.laborcosts, cl.calculationdate, cl.paintlabor, cl.paintmaterial,
        cl.currency, car.manufacturer, car.model, car.submodel,
        IFNULL(org.name, 0) as orgName, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(po.repairmethod LIKE 'L%',
                       po.text,NULL)
            ORDER BY  1) AS textL, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(po.repairmethod = 'E',
                       po.text,NULL
                          )
            ORDER BY  1) AS textE , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(po.repairmethod != 'E'
                      OR  (po.repairmethod = 'E'
                              AND  po.guidenumber = 'N/A'
                          )
                      AND  po.repairmethod NOT LIKE 'L%',po.text, NULL
                          )
            ORDER BY  1
              ) AS textO
    FROM  axnmrs_cases AS c
    LEFT JOIN  axnmrs_calculations as cl on c.case_id = cl.case_id
      AND  c.country = cl.country
    LEFT JOIN  axnmrs_positions as po on c.case_id = po.case_id
    LEFT JOIN  car_type as car on car.manufacturer_code = c.lastcalc_manufacturer_code
      AND  car.main_type = c.lastcalc_model_code
      AND  car.subtype_code = c.lastcalc_submodel_code
    LEFT JOIN  organization_list as org on org.memberId = c.insurer_memberid
    WHERE  c.vin= 'U5YFF24128L064909'
    GROUP BY  c.vin, c.case_id, c.axrmrs_id
```

And SECOND one with VIN = `VF38BRHZE80728805`  (this takes  2.4387 sec)

```
SELECT  c.vin, c.case_id, c.claimnumber, c.platenumber, c.axrmrs_id,
        c.insurer_memberid, c.country, c.date_created, c.totalloss,
        c.lastcalc_manufacturer_code, c.lastcalc_model_code, c.lastcalc_submodel_code,
        c.audavin_triggered, c.accident_date, c.registration_date,
        c.manufacturing_year, cl.spareparts, cl.totalcosts, cl.laborhours,
        cl.laborcosts, cl.calculationdate, cl.paintlabor, cl.paintmaterial,
        cl.currency, car.manufacturer, car.model, car.submodel,
        IFNULL(org.name, 0) as orgName, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(po.repairmethod LIKE 'L%',
                       po.text,NULL)
            ORDER BY  1) AS textL, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(po.repairmethod = 'E',
                       po.text,NULL
                          )
            ORDER BY  1) AS textE , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(po.repairmethod != 'E'
                      OR  (po.repairmethod = 'E'
                              AND  po.guidenumber = 'N/A'
                          )
                      AND  po.repairmethod NOT LIKE 'L%',po.text, NULL
                          )
            ORDER BY  1
              ) AS textO
    FROM  axnmrs_cases AS c
    LEFT JOIN  axnmrs_calculations as cl on c.case_id = cl.case_id
      AND  c.country = cl.country
    LEFT JOIN  axnmrs_positions as po on c.case_id = po.case_id
    LEFT JOIN  car_type as car on car.manufacturer_code = c.lastcalc_manufacturer_code
      AND  car.main_type = c.lastcalc_model_code
      AND  car.subtype_code = c.lastcalc_submodel_code
    LEFT JOIN  organization_list as org on org.memberId = c.insurer_memberid
    WHERE  c.vin= 'VF38BRHZE80728805'
    GROUP BY  c.vin, c.case_id, c.axrmrs_id
```

I have no clue why this happen so I try to analyze so i use "PROFILE" function in PHPMYADMIN which return me result as below on screens:
VIN: `U5YFF24128L064909`
[image]

And VIN: `VF38BRHZE80728805` (it is obviously longer operation )
[image]

Becuase i wasnt able to google anything usefull from this I also try EXPLAIN SELECT query which looks like this:
For VIN: `U5YFF24128L064909`
[image]

And for VIN: `VF38BRHZE80728805`
[image]

From this explain I think I'm doing bad query on car_type table which should be written better, however it will not change speed of same query just with different VIN number.

**I was also thinking that my first QUERY just return from CACHE and second come from DB. So i try to do both query again. And both again take same time as before.**

Is here anyone who can help me find what's the issue  of this query? What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you for any advise because I am lost in this already!

EDIT:
In `car_type` table I have indexes on: `manufacturer_code`, `main_type`, `subtype_code`

EDIT2:
To analyze deeper I try to SHOW CREATE TABLE {{table name}} and results are below.

axnmrs_cases:

```
CREATE TABLE `axnmrs_cases` (
    `axrmrs_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `case_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `axncase_guid` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `date_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
    `datasource` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `claimnumber` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `platenumber` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `displayname` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `vin` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `lastcalc_manufacturer_code` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `lastcalc_model_code` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `lastcalc_submodel_code` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `lastcalc_model_options` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `audavin_triggered` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `vehicletype` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `accident_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
    `date_closed` timestamp NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
    `claimowner_memberid` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `repairer_memberid` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `insurer_memberid` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `assessor_memberid` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `accidentcause_code` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `casetype_code` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `claimtype_code` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `damagecause_code` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `damagearea_codes` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `totalloss` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `inspectionrequired` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `manufacturing_year` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `registration_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
    `mileage` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `country` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
    KEY `VIN_index` (`vin`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3471525 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

axnmrs_calculations:

```
CREATE TABLE `axnmrs_calculations` (
    `calculation_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
    `case_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
    `guid` varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    `calculationdate` varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    `calsscalnr` varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    `model_options` varchar(60) NOT NULL, 
    `spareparts` varchar(60) NOT NULL, 
    `laborcosts` varchar(60) NOT NULL, 
    `paintlabor` varchar(60) NOT NULL, 
    `paintmaterial` varchar(40) NOT NULL, 
    `extracosts` varchar(60) NOT NULL, 
    `environmentalcosts` varchar(60) NOT NULL, 
    `totalcosts` varchar(60) NOT NULL, 
    `totalvat` varchar(60) NOT NULL, 
    `laborhours` varchar(60) NOT NULL, 
    `painthours` varchar(60) NOT NULL, 
    `totaldeduction` varchar(60) NOT NULL, 
    `partsadjustment` varchar(60) NOT NULL, 
    `calculationtype` varchar(60) NOT NULL, 
    `license` varchar(60) NOT NULL, 
    `memberrole` varchar(60) NOT NULL, 
    `currency` varchar(5) NOT NULL, 
    `country` varchar(2) NOT NULL, 
    KEY `caseid_index` (`case_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

axnmrs_positions:

```
CREATE TABLE `axnmrs_positions` (
    `calculation_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `case_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `position_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `blockline` varchar(7) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `repairmethod` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `guidenumber` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `amount` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `hours` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `starmutation` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `text` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `originalpartnumber` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `originalpartprice` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `manufacturercode` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `quality` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `suppliercode` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    KEY `calculationid_index` (`calculation_id`), 
    KEY `repairmethod` (`repairmethod`), 
    KEY `caseid_index` (`case_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

car_type:

```
CREATE TABLE `car_type` (
    `manufacturer_code` varchar(2) NOT NULL, 
    `main_type` varchar(2) NOT NULL, 
    `subtype_code` varchar(2) NOT NULL, 
    `manufacturer` varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    `model` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_czech_ci NOT NULL, 
    `submodel` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_czech_ci NOT NULL, 
    KEY `manufacturer_code` (`manufacturer_code`), 
    KEY `main_type` (`main_type`), 
    KEY `subtype_code` (`subtype_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

organization_list:

```
CREATE TABLE `organization_list` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `memberId` varchar(99) NOT NULL, 
    `name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_czech_ci NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
    KEY `memberId` (`memberId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=133 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Do you have an Index on that field? And how many records are in the table? Is it possible that the first VID is stored in the first records and the seconds VIN is in the end of the records?

Comment: When using PROFILE for troubleshooting this type of issue, multiple attempts are needed and the median time should be taken. This will ensure that if the query is cached as suggested in an answer below, you are giving the second query a chance to be cached before it is compared.

Comment: Hey @etalon11 I have indexes in every table in "car" table i have it on manufacturer_code,  main_type, subtype_code

I look at case_id whats basicly ID of each case and 1,5M and for second win its 500 000  ( full table have 3,5M) so I dont think this should be issue

Comment: Ok. Have you tried to comment out the different joins? Maybe it is one JOIN or GROUP_CONCAT which takes more time on execution as on the other VID. Maybe you can try to comment out one JOIN after an other and check the results. There has to be something different. For further analyse a model of your table structure would be helpful.

Comment: How large is the query result? The second result set could be too large to fit in the cache. Alternatively, try explicitely clearing the cache before your tests (`RESET QUERY CACHE;`);

Comment: My guess would be the same as what @RandomSeed wrote. Try increase query_cache_limit and also try running the queries with SQL_NO_CACHE to compare apples to apples. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-cache-in-select.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The profile gives you the answer -- the **Query cache**.

The only way to get a result from a query like that in only 0.2 is for it to be coming from the "Query cache".  This is a hash of selects to resultsets.  You apparently ran the query twice and this was the second timing.  Try again with `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...` to see how long it "really" takes.

Please note that the "Query cache" is not the only "cache" that MySQL uses; so be careful in using the terminology.

(And that's not 10x; that's 10000x longer.)

That aside, your next question will be **Why does such a query take 2.4 seconds?**  That is the question that you should address.  The clues are in the `EXPLAIN` -- First notice the huge "rows" for `car`.

```
    LEFT JOIN car_type as car
      on car.manufacturer_code = c.lastcalc_manufacturer_code
     AND car.main_type = c.lastcalc_model_code
     AND car.subtype_code = c.lastcalc_submodel_code
```

Adding this composite index to `car_type` will speed up that part of the query.

```
INDEX(manufacturer_code, main_type, subtype_code)
```

(The order does not matter in this case.)

Also,

```
    LEFT JOIN organization_list as org on org.memberId = c.insurer_memberid
```

needs a consistent definition for memberId.  Look carefully at the `CHARACTER SET` in the two tables.

Use `ALTER TABLE ... CONVERT TO ...` to fix this issue so that it can use the index.

See also [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: Yikes -- I see at least 3 different `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION` combinations.  This may be causing other troubles.

Comment: You may want to disable query cache to confirm this assumption (SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM TABLE), also you may read this: [MySQL's Query Cache](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3110171/MySQLs-Query-Cache.htm)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your first result was stored and therefore retrieved from the "Query cache". Looking at the profile on 2. Almost all the time is spent writing the result to a table in order to cache the result.

Try checking the direct disk IO graph on the DB if you can

Comment: Hi Derrick sorry that I didnt mentioned that in question. I think the same way at start, so I try to repeat same query for second VIN as well but still take same time :(

Comment: With such a selective query being ran on car can you add a joint index to the columns you're adding? The explain plan shows that there isn't one now... at least that's how I'm reading it. From previous experience, if your result would return more than about 8% of a table the optimizer just does a full table scan regardless. Which can get pretty hairy on your join. Maybe it would be pertinent to do your join as a sub query?

Comment: @Andurit - "take same time" -- even adding blank space to the query causes a new entry in the QC.  Also, if the query was flushed (for whatever reason), it would not be in the QC.  Etc.